# Implement Push notifications in DRF and ReactJS

Tags: django, reactjs, firebase, django-rest-framework, push-notification

I am a beginner so please forgive me if I sound silly. I am trying to make a Rest API using DRF and am using serializers for connecting the models and retrieving the data in ReactJS using the fetch method.
I wanted to have the functionality of push notifications, and use the data of the different models in the notifications.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should follow these steps

- create an FCM (firebase cloud messaging) account
- create an application in FCM
- implement [django-fcm](https://django-fcm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in backend
- make an api for getting registration_id from client simply named **sync-device**
- implement [react-fcm](https://github.com/pavelpashkovsky/react-fcm) in client side

good luck ;)